# ServiceStack OAuth Issue with Github

Tags: oauth-2.0, servicestack

I'm using the dotnet core 3.1, latest version of ServiceStack and I'm trying to use Google, Microsoft, and Github OAuth with it.

So far with Google and Microsoft, I don't have any issues, however, with Github when I navigate to: `/auth` and click on 'Github' button.

I'm being redirected to GitHub and presented with the consent page.

```
Personal user data
Full access
```

When I click `Authorize` I'm beeing redirected back to my localhost to: `/login#f=AccessTokenFailed`

If I login to my Developers Setting I see that 1 user.

So, I'm not sure if this is some workflow issue in ServiceStack maybe, or something with my implementation.

As per my implementation, I have this:

`appsettings.json`

```
"oauth.github.Scopes": "user,user:email",
"oauth.github.ClientId" :"xxx",
"oauth.github.ClientSecret": "xxx",
```

...

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
            () => new AuthUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[] {
                new JwtAuthProvider
                {
                    HashAlgorithm = "HS256",
                    RequireSecureConnection = false, 
                    AuthKeyBase64 = "xxx", 
                    CreatePayloadFilter = (payload,session) => {},
                    PopulateSessionFilter = (session, token, req) => {}
                },
                new GoogleAuthProvider(appSettings),
                new GithubAuthProvider(appSettings),
                new MicrosoftGraphAuthProvider(appSettings)                }
        ));
```

After initial redirect back to my app, when I navigate again to /auth I see I'm not logged in, but when I click again on Github button, I just get redirected back again with the same error message in URL (AccessTokenFailed) (no consent prompt or anything).

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to new [GitHub OAuth Apps requiring access tokens](https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-10-deprecating-auth-through-query-param/) to be submitted via Authorization Header which has now been resolved from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/77fe75c0d0b5ab931bc5228510248de56e7d1324).

This change is now available from the latest v5.9.3+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).